# Событие открытия модального окна Fancybox

Tags: javascript, fancybox

Использую fancybox для открытия модальных окон. Появился вопрос. Я знаю что есть ивенты при инициализации. А есть ли глобальные ивенты? к примеру ивент который срабатывает когда открывается любое модальное окно.

Нужно отследить открытие модального окна.

Comment: fancybox или fancybox 2?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский который отсюда http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/. И как я понимаю это 2

Comment: вас чем-то не устроили методы в [документации](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) на вкладке `Callbacks` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я же написал что это при инициализации. Я про это в курсе. Меня интересует глобальный ивент.

Comment: Ну а чем это не глобальный? Допустим все ссылки, при нажатии на которую должен вызываться fancybox имеют класс `.fancy` ......делаете для всех `$(".fancy").fancybox({
    beforeLoad: someCallback
});` .........а для конкретных пишите дополнительные инициализирующие методы с более конкретными тонкими настройками..... как вариант делается общая функция и пляшем в зависимости от переданных данных.... что-то типа http://stackoverflow.com/a/5094275/6104996

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать свою функцию для этого.

```js
function detect(){
console.log('Fancy Box Открылся');
}
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
      afterShow: detect,
        helpers: {
            thumbs: {
                width  : 40,
                height : 40,
                source  : function(current) {
                    return $(current.element).data('thumbnail');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>

<a class="fancybox" data-thumbnail="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">Open #1</a>

<br />

<a class="fancybox" data-thumbnail="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg">Open #2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

У плагина есть настройки по умолчанию

```
$.fancybox.defaults
```

Указав нужное значение тут можно будет не прописывать в опциях для конкретного экземпляра, например:

```
$.fancybox.defaults.afterShow = function(){ ... };
```